# Ignore missing columns in 'usecol' parameter

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading a table from csv and only want a subset of the columns. The list I'm using to subset contains field names that may not exist in the table I'm reading.  For example:

```
# contents of sample.csv:
#a,b,c
#1,2,3
#4,5,6

subset = ['a', 'c', 'd']
```

I'd like to return the following, using pandas.read_csv and the subset, but this raises an error:

```
pd.read_csv(sample.csv, usecols=subset)
a  c
1  3
4  6

ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ['d']
```

I think I might be able to do with a callable value for usecols, but am not sure how to implement.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a callable checking if the column is `in` the subset

```
subset = ['a', 'c', 'd']
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', usecols=lambda x: x in subset)

   a  c
0  1  3
1  4  6
```

Answer (score -1):

It is throwing error because as per your CSV file, columns are a,b,c.
But in your subset you are trying to fetch a,b,d.
But column d is not present in your sample.